# How to make my image full width with bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to make this work, my image stays in the middle of the screen on desktop mode, even I removed the padding on `.container-fluid` it stays there in the middle, when I resize the browser it takes the full width, which I want, but not in desktop mode.

Here is the code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="img/imgBG.jpg" alt="BGDentist" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img-responsive {
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-fluid {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it's because the image width is < whatever the container is, but can't say for certain since you didn't link to the actual image. Have you tried `width: 100%;` on the image? It would be great if you included a fully working demo of the issue.

Comment: I agree, I bet it is because your image isn't large enough but hard to know for sure without a link or working code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). My first guess is that your image stops being responsive (expanding/shrinking) because the image has expanded to its native resolution. Once that happens it will stop enlarging as `max-width` is set to `100%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a verifiable example I'm going to guess it's because your image isn't large enough to expand into it's container at larger viewport sizes.

Your typical responsive image class looks like this:

```
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

The `max-width` property is what's limiting your image from expanding after a certain point.  When set to `100%` the max width the image will be what ever it's natural width is. If you have a `400px` wide image, the image will expand/shrink when its container element is 400px or less. If the container is more than 400px it stops expanding.

The reason `max-width: 100%;` is used is to help keep your imagery sharp. You can use `width: 100%;` in place of `max-width` but your images will become blurry and pixelate once stretched beyond their native resolution.

Below is and example of what I believe you are experiencing. Below this example is another using `width: 100%;`.

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x200/">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x200/ff0">
</div>
```

Pixelates after container is larger than image's native `400px` width.

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200/">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, My image was less than the container fluid.Now it is working and it covering full width. I just  had to add widh 100%

Comment: Cool. Please accept answer and remember that your image will blur/pixelate once stretched beyond its native resolution.